# SQL Query optimization Issue with order by - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, similarity

I need to optimize a query that finds similar data in the table based on given value.

The query that needs to be optimized is...

```
select 
  * 
from 
  (
    select 
      *, 
      (
        (
          score_StateCode + score_DisplayName
        )/ 3
      ) as matching_score 
    from 
      (
        select 
          *, 
          SIMILARITY("StateCode" :: text, 'CA') AS score_StateCode, 
          SIMILARITY(
            "DisplayName" :: text, 'A+ ROOFING & CONSTRUCTION'
          ) AS score_DisplayName 
        from 
          (
            select 
              * 
            from 
              customer_search_source 
            where 
              "CountryCode" = 'US'
          ) as new_table
      ) as nTable 
    order by 
      matching_score desc
  ) as s_table 
order by 
  matching_score desc 
limit 
  200;
```

The output of the "explain analyze" command is

```
Limit  (cost=19480.77..19506.10 rows=200 width=304) (actual time=577.034..584.769 rows=200 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=19480.77..32564.21 rows=112136 width=304) (actual time=577.031..584.512 rows=200 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Sort  (cost=18480.74..18620.91 rows=56068 width=304) (actual time=574.211..574.425 rows=215 loops=3)
              Sort Key: (((similarity((customer_search_source."StateCode")::text, 'CA'::text) + similarity(customer_search_source."DisplayName", 'A+ ROOFING & CONSTRUCTION'::text)) / '3'::double precision)) DESC
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 12208kB
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on customer_search_source  (cost=0.00..6200.91 rows=56068 width=304) (actual time=0.064..478.160 rows=44856 loops=3)
                    Filter: (("CountryCode")::text = 'US'::text)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning time: 0.755 ms
Execution time: 588.093 ms
```

Note: customer_search_source is a materialized view. Also I tried this query in a actual table that had same data and results were similar...
Schema for the view is:

```
SELECT customer."CustTreeNodeID",
    customer.id,
    customer."DisplayName",
    customer."CustomerNumber",
    email."EmailID",
    email."Email",
    phone."PhoneID",
    phone."PhoneNumber",
    address."AddressID",
    address."Street",
    address."Street2",
    address."City",
    address."StateCode",
    address."PostalCode",
    address."County",
    address."CountryCode",
    address."ZipPrefix",
    address."GeoCode",
    address."Latitude",
    address."Longitude",
    address."GeoCodeLocked",
    address."ErrorCode",
    address."Override",
    address."LocGeography",
    address."NeedsGeoUpdate",
    address."BillingContactName"
   FROM (((search_data_customer customer
     LEFT JOIN ( SELECT e."CustTreeNodeID",
            e."EmailID",
            e."Email"
           FROM search_data_email e) email USING ("CustTreeNodeID"))
     LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ph."CustTreeNodeID",
            ph."PhoneID",
            ph."PhoneNumber"
           FROM search_data_phone ph) phone USING ("CustTreeNodeID"))
     LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ad."CustTreeNodeID",
            ad."AddressID",
            ad."Street",
            ad."Street2",
            ad."City",
            ad."StateCode",
            ad."PostalCode",
            ad."County",
            ad."CountryCode",
            ad."ZipPrefix",
            ad."GeoCode",
            ad."Latitude",
            ad."Longitude",
            ad."GeoCodeLocked",
            ad."ErrorCode",
            ad."Override",
            ad."LocGeography",
            ad."NeedsGeoUpdate",
            ad."BillingContactName"
           FROM search_data_address ad) address USING ("CustTreeNodeID"));
```

As I want to get any matching data that is present in the database i cant add filters. I can reduce the speed by allowing multi-threading but in is not optimal since this query is to be run for multiple data set in parallel...

From what I can understand the query is taking time because of order by clause... since after removing it it takes 2ms for the script to execute...

I tried different indexing method and some filtering methods too... but in the end i can at most reduce the data set to 20k and than sorting takes similar time...

I want to know is there a way to optimize this query while making sure i can get closes matching results from it.

I tried below methods:

1. Indexing - Didn't help any because the actual conditions didn't take time..
2. Filtering - even after i set a threshold for similarity at 0.05 the result always exceed 15K and sorting takes similar time
3. Remove sub-query and make it a single query - it actually increased the time it take for the query to process
4. Use WITH clause - i tried taking this query as temp schema while removing order by... and than split the data and then sort it... the time increased instead of decreasing
5. Reduce the limit to 50 - same timing

@Zegarek

I have added indexing for all fields. Also the indexes ore of 3 types, 1 basic and rest are like below sample...

```
CREATE INDEX materialized_view_index_tp_ops2_phonenumber ON public.customer_search_source USING btree ("PhoneNumber")
CREATE INDEX materialized_view_index_tp_ops_statecode ON public.customer_search_source USING btree ("PhoneNumber" text_pattern_ops)
```

Schema for the tables are as below:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."search_data_address" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL,
    "CustTreeNodeID" character varying(256),
    "AddressID" character varying(256),
    "LegacyValue" text,
    "AddressTypeCode" character varying(256),
    "AddressName" text,
    "Street" text,
    "Street2" text,
    "City" text,
    "StateCode" character varying(256),
    "PostalCode" character varying(256),
    "County" text,
    "CreateID" character varying(256),
    "CreateDate" character varying(256),
    "LastModfID" character varying(256),
    "LastModfDate" character varying(256),
    "Locked" text,
    "Active" text,
    "ZipPrefix" text,
    "GeoCode" character varying(256),
    "Latitude" text,
    "Longitude" text,
    "CountryCode" character varying(256),
    "GeoCodeLocked" character varying(256),
    "ErrorCode" character varying(256),
    "Override" text,
    "LocGeography" text,
    "NeedsGeoUpdate" text,
    "BillingContactTypeID" character varying(256),
    "BillingContactName" text,
    "DeliveryAddressTypeID" character varying(256),
    "AddressTypeID" character varying(256),
    "ExternalSystemID" character varying(256),
    "IsCleaned" character varying(256)
) WITH (oids = false);

CREATE TABLE "public"."search_data_customer" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL,
    "CustTreeNodeID" character varying(256),
    "DisplayName" text,
    "CustomerNumber" text
) WITH (oids = false);

CREATE TABLE "public"."search_data_email" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL,
    "EmailID" character varying(256),
    "CustTreeNodeID" character varying(256),
    "CreateDate" character varying(256),
    "IsPrimary" character varying(256),
    "Email" text,
    "OptIn" text,
    "C_LescoFlag" text,
    "OldEmailID" character varying(256),
    "CreateID" character varying(256),
    "LastModfDate" character varying(256),
    "LastModfID" character varying(256),
    "OptInEquipment" text,
    "OptInEvents" text,
    "OptInProducts" text,
    "OptInGreenCat" text,
    "ExternalSystemID" character varying(256)
) WITH (oids = false);

CREATE TABLE "public"."search_data_phone" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL,
    "CustTreeNodeID" character varying(256),
    "PhoneID" character varying(256),
    "PhoneTypeID" character varying(256),
    "PhoneNumber" text,
    "Extension" text,
    "Notes" text,
    "CreateDate" character varying(256),
    "CreateID" character varying(256),
    "LastModfDate" character varying(256),
    "LastModfID" character varying(256),
    "Locked" text,
    "Active" text,
    "LegacyValue" text,
    "ExternalSystemID" character varying(256)
) WITH (oids = false);
```

@jjanes
Postgresql Version is as below

```
$ psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.22 (Debian 10.22-1.pgdg90+1)
```

Multi-threading is Enabled but since I need to run thousand of this query, I need to run them in parallel too... so the end result gets affected by the amount of time a single query needs..

State code is just a example of columns it can be any column like "Street" etc...

I am using this to find similar users in our database.. and while this query is ok for single user check. I get a list of 10K users that needs to be checked... this takes more than 2 hour when running this query for each user... I need to reduce this time to at least 1 hour..

Currently there are only 100K users in our database that i am checking... but this can go up to million.. And since number of records adversely affect the execution time I am hoping to find a alternative or optimize the given query...

Comment: You definitely don't need the inner `order by` in the subquery - but removing both speeds things up only because without them, you're effectively taking first 200 *random* rows. Reducing `limit` only changes how much of the result you'll discard, without affecting how the entire thing was calculated. It would help if you showed what indexes and filters you tested, and how - examples for each of your 5 points. It also helps if we can reproduce this with `create table` statements for `search_data_email`, `search_data_phone`, `search_data_address` and some random test samples (not real data).

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: "I can reduce the speed by allowing multi-threading but in is not optimal since this query is to be run for multiple data set in parallel..."  But you **are** allowing parallel processing.  Your plan shows it happening.

Comment: I don't know what using a gratuitously complex query does for you, but it certainly makes our job harder.

Comment: Your "StateCode" similarity doesn't make sense.  Should California really be more similar to Connecticut than it is to Oregon?  And Oregon more similar to Ohio?  Were it not for that, you might be able to use a gist_trgm_ops index with the `<->` operator.